# How to exclude an HTML element form Ionic CSS

Tags: angularjs, html, css, ionic-framework

I have a particular rounded button, with his CSS, but when I use it, my CSS blow up, because there are Ionic CSS "standard" rules. 
My `.button` class is ruinded by the `.button` CSS class of Ionic.

I already tried to change name to my `.button` class but nothing. The only way to get my button is to not import the **Ionic.css** file, but of course, I need it for the other elements,

My button is nested inside other elements, for which I need the Ionic CSS

So, I need to know if is possible to exclude a specific HTML tag from the Ionic CSS rules, without edit  **Ionic.css**  file

Comment: Have you try with !important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. Go into the Ionic.css and Edit it. You can edit it. I checked the Docu for Sass: http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/sass.html The CSS is placed in this folder: www/lib/ionic/css The better solution is, to set up an Sass environment. Then you can use only the components you need.

And other solution, but a bit dirty, is, to override the rule with a deeper selector. Maybe with .container .button or div.button or button.button or body .button.

Comment: I tried to create a new class called "newClassButton" in the Ionic.css, but still not working (my button is still ruined by Ionic CSS). I will read the docs, thank you dude.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other class name in your custom css and use the property `!important` in each of your css rules. Anyway you could change the order of the imports.

Comment: !important is not working. I can't change the order, cause I import the Ionic.css in the Index, so the view are under that css rules